# Turning a non-vectorized code into a vectorized one

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have already discovered that this function is my bottleneck and that I need to make it more efficient.

So, to speed it up, I thought about using numpy vector operations, but I haven't been able to do it yet. I know that with this vectorization, I can ensure that I don't have a for loop within another for loop, but I have no idea how to do this practically because the output has to remain the same.  I have this so far:

```
def filtered_lines_calculation(lines):
    '''
    This function is used for reducing all the hough-lines (from detect_grid) within a certain threshold to 1 line.
    '''
    if RESOLUTION == 0:
        threshold = 75
    elif RESOLUTION == 1:
        threshold = 50
    elif RESOLUTION == 2:
        threshold = 30

    lines = np.array(lines)
    filtered_lines = []

    # Calculate the orientation (horizontal or vertical)
    slopes = (lines[:, :, 3] - lines[:, :, 1]) / (lines[:, :, 2] - lines[:, :, 0])
    slopes[np.isinf(slopes)] = 1e6  # Avoid division by zero for vertical lines

    for line_index, line in enumerate(lines):
        p1, p2 = line[0][:2], line[0][2:]
        too_close = False

        slope = slopes[line_index]

        # We can convert filtered_lines to a numpy array and process it faster
        filtered_lines_array = np.array(filtered_lines)

        for other_line in filtered_lines_array:
            p3, p4 = other_line[:2], other_line[2:]
            other_slope = (p4[1] - p3[1]) / (p4[0] - p3[0]) if (p4[0] - p3[0]) != 0 else 1e6

            if (abs(slope) < 1 and abs(other_slope) < 1) or (abs(slope) > 1 and abs(other_slope) > 1):
                distance = np.linalg.norm(np.cross(p2 - p1, p1 - p3)) / np.linalg.norm(p2 - p1)
                if distance < threshold:
                    too_close = True
                    break

        if not too_close:
            filtered_lines.append(line[0])

    return filtered_lines
```

where Lines is just a list of lines, something like this:

[[[  0  40 211  47]]

[[  0  91 211  98]]

[[  6  92 211  99]]

[[ 27  42 211  49]]

[[173   1 184 118]]

[[ 19 118  34   0]]

[[ 75 118  81   1]]

[[  0  39 191  46]]

[[129   0 131 118]]

[[ 76 118  82   0]]]

Comment: What is `lines`? Perhaps you can [edit] your question and put there sample (small) input data.

Comment: In most cases, when you have trouble with vectorizing, `numba` package will be your friend. You just need to learn what can and what cannot be used in the function in order for it to be numba-compatible.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I edited the question, and as output I would like to have such a list of lines preferably as well. I am not sure vectorizing is the best way to do it, but when i searched for the fastest way to do such calculations, this was the fastest one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly modified [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) version - the modification is that now the function returns list of indices (you can filter your original list `lines` with this list to obtain desired result).

Other thing is, now you must supply `np.array` as function parameter as well:

```py
from timeit import timeit

from numba import njit
from numba.np.extensions import cross2d
from numba.typed import List


def filtered_lines_calculation(lines, RESOLUTION):
    """
    This function is used for reducing all the hough-lines (from detect_grid) within a certain threshold to 1 line.
    """
    if RESOLUTION == 0:
        threshold = 75
    elif RESOLUTION == 1:
        threshold = 50
    elif RESOLUTION == 2:
        threshold = 30

    filtered_lines = []

    # Calculate the orientation (horizontal or vertical)
    slopes = (lines[:, :, 3] - lines[:, :, 1]) / (lines[:, :, 2] - lines[:, :, 0])
    slopes[np.isinf(slopes)] = 1e6  # Avoid division by zero for vertical lines

    for line_index, line in enumerate(lines):
        p1, p2 = line[0][:2], line[0][2:]
        too_close = False

        slope = slopes[line_index]

        for other_line in filtered_lines:
            p3, p4 = other_line[:2], other_line[2:]

            other_slope = (
                (p4[1] - p3[1]) / (p4[0] - p3[0]) if (p4[0] - p3[0]) != 0 else 1e6
            )

            if (abs(slope) < 1 and abs(other_slope) < 1) or (
                abs(slope) > 1 and abs(other_slope) > 1
            ):
                distance = np.abs(np.cross(p2 - p1, p1 - p3)) / np.linalg.norm(p2 - p1)
                if distance < threshold:
                    too_close = True
                    break

        if not too_close:
            filtered_lines.append(line[0])

    return filtered_lines


@njit
def numba_norm(a):
    return np.sqrt(a[0] * a[0] + a[1] * a[1])


@njit
def filtered_lines_calculation_numba(lines, RESOLUTION):
    """
    This function is used for reducing all the hough-lines (from detect_grid) within a certain threshold to 1 line.
    """
    if RESOLUTION == 0:
        threshold = 75
    elif RESOLUTION == 1:
        threshold = 50
    elif RESOLUTION == 2:
        threshold = 30

    filtered_lines = List.empty_list(np.int64)

    slopes = (lines[:, :, 3] - lines[:, :, 1]) / (lines[:, :, 2] - lines[:, :, 0])

    mask = np.isinf(slopes)[:, 0]
    slopes[mask] = 1e6  # Avoid division by zero for vertical lines

    for line_index, line in enumerate(lines):
        p1, p2 = line[0][:2], line[0][2:]
        too_close = False

        slope = slopes[line_index]

        for idx in filtered_lines:
            other_line = lines[idx][0]

            p3, p4 = other_line[:2], other_line[2:]

            tmp = p4[0] - p3[0]

            if tmp == 0:
                tmp = 1e6

            other_slope = (p4[1] - p3[1]) / tmp

            if (np.abs(slope) < 1 and np.abs(other_slope) < 1) or (
                np.abs(slope) > 1 and np.abs(other_slope) > 1
            ):
                distance = np.abs(cross2d(p2 - p1, p1 - p3)) / numba_norm(p2 - p1)
                if distance < threshold:
                    too_close = True
                    break

        if not too_close:
            filtered_lines.append(line_index)

    return filtered_lines


RESOLUTION = 1

lines = np.array(
    [
        [[0, 40, 211, 47]],
        [[0, 91, 211, 98]],
        [[6, 92, 211, 99]],
        [[27, 42, 211, 49]],
        [[173, 1, 184, 118]],
        [[19, 118, 34, 0]],
        [[75, 118, 81, 1]],
        [[0, 39, 191, 46]],
        [[129, 0, 131, 118]],
        [[76, 118, 82, 0]],
    ]
)


# check if the computation is correct + compile the numba function:
out1 = filtered_lines_calculation(lines, RESOLUTION)
out2 = filtered_lines_calculation_numba(lines, RESOLUTION)

assert all(np.allclose(i, j[0]) for i, j in zip(out1, lines[out2]))


# make bigger input to perform the test
lines = np.concatenate([lines for _ in range(10000)])

t1 = timeit(
    "filtered_lines_calculation(lines, RESOLUTION)", number=1, globals=globals()
)

t2 = timeit(
    "lines[filtered_lines_calculation_numba(lines, RESOLUTION)]",
    number=1,
    globals=globals(),
)

print(f"Time normal = {t1}")
print(f"Time numba  = {t2}")
```

This prints on my machine AMD 5700x:

```
Time normal = 3.1929642129689455
Time numba  = 0.032550607807934284
```

Comment: Thanks! It is indeed a lot faster, do you know where i can read a bit more about this 'Numba-package'? I would like to learn more about this :)

Comment: @Bert Official page is good start: https://numba.pydata.org/ Also, there are lots of examples here on StackOverflow under the tag [tag:numba]

Comment: Thanks! The problem I have now is that the cumulative time of my own functions is less than 0.001 seconds, but the cumulative time of some of the numba functions is like 3 seconds or more. So like now i don't know how to further improve my fps...

Comment: @Bert did you compile the numba functions before running? When jitted function is run for first time it takes some time to compile it. Next runs should be fine.